# How to by pass Middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, express

How to by pass middleware M2 and jump to M3 if some condition is full fill in M1.

```
var middleware = [M1,M2,M3];
app.post('/order/', middleware, finalMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Express Conditional Middleware`](https://github.com/elliotttf/express-conditional-middleware):

```
var conditional = require('express-conditional-middleware');

var middlewares = [M1,M2,M3];
app.post('/order/', conditional.apply(null, middlewares));
```

Comment: where do you state the condition ?

Comment: In middleware M1 I have a condition if that full fill then M2 should be called else it should jump to M3.

Answer (score 0):

Or for more complex logic you can use this:
[Express Conditional Tree Middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-conditional-tree-middleware).

Check out the docs, its easy to use and provides functionality so that you can use it with async middleware too! For your example, I suppose you can use an orChainer between your M1 and M2 middleware so if M1 is fulfilled then M2 will not be executed and put this orChainer under an andChainer (think of it as a tree) alongside with the M3 middleware. Hope you find this useful, good luck! :)